# Dynamics CRM Plugin Email - Sql Encryption Symmetric Key Error

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-365

I am getting some kind of Encryption error when I try and send an email in a plugin (action). I have two environments that are the same.  It works in dev but when I deploy it to a UAT environment, i get the following error on the workflow that fires the action when the action tries to create/send an email. Neither environment is HTTPS.  A lot of posts online say to go to Settings->Data Management->Data Encryption but that box will not open as its not HTTPS.

> Cannot open Sql Encryption Symmetric Key because Symmetric Key
>   password does not exist in Config DB

If anyone has any pointers that would be awesome.
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi sending an email in CRM requires data encryption to be enabled, if you check your `dev` environment i believe the `Data Encryption` will be `Active`(Go to Settings->Data management –> Data Encryption) as below image that is why your `Plugin` is working fine in `dev` environment.

**You need to enable `Data Encryption` in your UAT environment.**

[image: Data Encyption]

Please try the following steps:

**1.** Disable SSL Check (Non HTTPS deployment – if you use HTTPS
    deployment, skip this step)

**2.** Run the following SQL for MSCRM_CONFIG database.

```
      UPDATE [MSCRM_CONFIG].[dbo].[DeploymentProperties]
      SET [BitColumn]=1
      WHERE ColumnName='DisableSSLCheckForEncryption'
```

**3.**  Go to Settings->Data management –> Data Encryption

**4.**  Enter any encryption key, it could be anything and click activate.
[image]

**Please read more about Data Encryption and Encryption key here:**

[Data Encryption in CRM 2013](http://www.inogic.com/blog/2014/03/data-encryption-in-crm-2013/)

[CRM 2013: CRM And SQL Encryption](https://dynamicscrmgirl.wordpress.com/2013/11/07/crm-2013-crm-and-sql-encryption/)

[Data Encryption Feature Isn’t Activated](https://dynamicscrmpros.com/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2013-data-encryption-feature-isnt-activated-error-moving-database-online-premise-environment/)

[CRM 2013 Create Email error](https://dynamicsofdynamicscrm.com/2014/04/15/crm-2013-create-email-error-cannot-open-sql-encryption-symmetric-key-because-symmetric-key-password-does-not-exist-in-config-db/)